# Under-extrusion near the seam

Tags: underextrusion, flsun-qq

I have an FLSUN QQ-S Pro and I'm trying to print a part consisting only of thin walls with PLA. I'm using Cura 4.8.0, "FLSUS QQ-S" profile. Unfortunately, near the seam there are signs of underextrustion. It only happens near the seam, and after a few millimeters the wall is nice and smooth again.

[image: underextrustion]

Things I've tried:

1. Increasing hotend temperature to 210 °C
2. Setting flow rate compensation factor to 105 % (can't go much higher as the wall thickness will go up from current 0.4 mm - which is the desired result for this printer)
3. Disabling retraction
4. Enabling ironing

None of that helped. Is there some way to push filament a little bit forward at the start of each layer?

Comment: What does the coasting setting look like in your Cura setup ?

Comment: @ManfredR it's disabled